# To read something to the end (which verb to use)

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the verb that means to read a book (a newspaper article) from the beginning to the end. Is there such a verb in English?

> Yesterday I encountered an interesting article about chondroitin drugs. I [...] in one breath.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say they're going to be imbibe metaphors of questionable acceptability. Ingest, devour, absorb, down, imbibe ... You'd need to switch 'breath' to 'gulp'.

Comment: I read it *from start to finish / in one go / in a single sitting*.  I couldn't put it down. I started it and couldn't stop (til the end). It was unputdownable.  NONE, I realise, is a simple verb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Read-through"** and **"peruse"** can be construed as "skimming the important parts". Although it doesn't work for magazine or newspaper articles, the expression "I read it ***cover-to-cover***," expresses a thorough, complete reading of a book, script, or report.

Answer (score 1):

How about [obserb](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=obserb)? Yesterday I encountered an interesting article about chondroitin drugs. I [obserb](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=obserb)ed in one breath.

Or

[finished](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/finished)

Answer (score 0):

I think  [peruse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peruse)  may fit in your context:

> - read; especially :  to read over in an attentive or leisurely manner.
> - to examine or consider with attention and in detail .

- Some lecturers seem to have an aversion to using the electronic version and would much prefer to peruse the printed copy.
- Let us now peruse the tarnished pages of history.

also: [pore over](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pore+over):

> - To read or study something carefully and thoroughly.

Comment: Is **"read through"** also correct?

Comment: Yes, you can say 'read through  a book'!!

Comment: _Peruse_ seems to have two almost contradictory meanings... to look at or read (something) in an informal or relaxed way / to examine or read (something) in a very careful way.

Comment: @oerkelens - True, that depends on context: The judge will want to peruse your incident report, so don't forget to bring it! (Read with attention)!!!





I am sitting in a waiting room with no magazine to peruse! ( leisure)

Comment: Read through! That's the word.

Comment: @Josh61 Where there _is_ adequate context. 'I was perusing my travel guide to Wales last night.' (??)